# XSLT - Extract data from textfile located within the same jar file using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, jar

To avoid hardcoding some strings in XSLT transformation files, I created a getString template that allows me to grab a string from a file using a specific key. The path to the file changes depending on the language (english or french) of the XML being transformed and on the $form variable passed as an argument.

The method is tested and works great in a normal project, but as soon as the project is compiled in a jar file and uploaded on a linux server, getString stops working properly.

After looking at the error logs, it seems that the path getString tries to reach when it is in a jar file is invalid. I tried using the function resolve-uri to return the correct absolute path but I get the same error when tried in the jar file. Can anyone help me?

Here is the XSLT template. The function used to parse the external file is:
unparsed-text($path)

```
    <xsl:template name="getString">
    <xsl:param name="key" />
    <xsl:param name="form" />
    <xsl:variable name="path">
        <xsl:variable name="basePath"
            select="concat('../../../reports/Resources/',$form)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="caseXmlData/header/language = 'fr_CA'">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($basePath, '/', $form, '_string_fr_CA.txt')" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="caseXmlData/header/language = 'en_CA'">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($basePath, '/', $form, '_string_en_CA.txt')" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($basePath, '/', $form, '_string_default.txt')" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="properties" select="unparsed-text($path)" />
    <xsl:variable name="lines" select="
      for $x in  
        for $i in tokenize($properties, '\n')[matches(., '^[^!#]')] 
            return tokenize($i, '=')[2]
        return translate(translate(normalize-space($x), '\', ''), '|', '')" />
    <xsl:variable name="keys" select="
      for $x in  
        for $i in tokenize($properties, '\n')[matches(., '^[^!#]')] 
            return tokenize($i, '=')[1]
        return normalize-space($x)" />
    <xsl:sequence select="$lines[index-of($keys, $key)]" />
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: The processor is Saxon HE

Comment: What xsl processor are you using?

Comment: I am using Saxon HE

Comment: I think in [xalanj](http://xalan.apache.org) there is a possibility to implement an URLLoader that might allow you to write java code to get access to the jar contents, but there might be something like that for Saxon too, maybe Michal Kay drops in who could know that. Or you might check the saxon docs in that direction.